# What is the difference bеtween fields?

Tags: choice-field, person, multi-select

I have two task lists in SP 2013.

- At first list the user-type field is shown like this

[image]

- and other list has a user-type field without choice features

[image]

How can I do a field in list 1 like field in a list2?

Comment: Can you please explain this in detail?

Comment: It seems the first list has a customised view.

Comment: Does the second one have auto-complete or just a blank input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, they removed the Check Name and Browse Settings from the people field.

Now chances are, Field in List 1 is coming from an upgrade (from 2010 to 2013) or someone applied the customization on it.

read this to see how to convert the 2nd list field. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692168/how-to-show-browse-and-check-names-button-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats it.  The reason -  at first list  i made a form in SPD. Second list - native SP 2013 form.

Comment: That's awesome, if it is helpful please mark it as answer so that other get benifits from it

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between these fields and how to make them show up in SharePoint 2013 is related to whether or not InfoPath is being used from my experience.

The first field with the "check names" and "address book" button can be found when you have people picker fields and you use InfoPath to handle the form.

The second type is the default people picker field that comes with SharePoint 2013 and will display in a list that is *not* using InfoPath. The nice thing about this one is that it remembers what people you have searched for before so you can find them again easily (this can be reset when you clear your browser cache).

Both do the same thing at the end of the day. Sometimes I encourage site designers to include some sort of description to help users understand how to use the field. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first field is "person or group (from directory) you can modify your second list field by customizing the form
see picture below[image]